# "Говори (-) не говори, толку не будет". Нужно ли тире перед "не говори"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Говори (—) не говори, толку не будет.

Нужно ли тире перед "не говори"?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, здесь вообще нет единого варианта написания и решение остаётся за автором.

Примеры для подобных случаев из "Нацкорпуса русского языка":

> Значит, хочешь не хочешь, а надо возвращаться.

> Но ещё через час хочешь, не хочешь, а приходилось вставать

> Но старайся не старайся, а хочешь не хочешь ― рассмотришь.

> Старайся ― не старайся, достиг ― не достиг: конец этого бесстыдства один

> Торопись, не торопись, старайся, не старайся, до первого стоящего отвеса ― час.